# What are relativistic effects on classical sine wave?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, waves

I am a high school student and recently heard of S. R. so I am excited to know what are its effect on sine wave in a string. Is there any change in wavelength, frequency , interference pattern etc.

Comment: If you mean an everyday object like a violin string, the effects are negligible.

Comment: Imagining a special string in which wave move at speed comparable to light.

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested and now studying SR and GR. From my viewpoint, in the ideal case(ignore the effect of gravity), the vibration equation of a string is $$\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}-a^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}=0, & -\infty<x<\infty,  t>0\\
\left.u(x, t)\right|_{t=0}=\phi(x), & -\infty<x<\infty \\
\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}=\psi(x), & -\infty<x<\infty
\end{array}
\end{equation}$$
notice that in equation there is $a^2$, where $a$ is the speed of wave, which implies that the information of a certain point in a string can not reach arbitrary point with infinite speed,to be specific,one can get the solution of $$\begin{equation}
u(x, t) =\frac{1}{2}[\phi(x-a t)+\phi(x+a t)]+\frac{1}{2 a} \int_{x-a t}^{x+a t} \psi(\xi) \mathrm{d} \xi .
\end{equation}$$

$\phi(x)$is the initial excited wave at t=0. the solution shows that vibration at x=x0 at t=0, then it will only effect the region:$[x-at,x+at]$ symmetrically. if you restric that the speed within the speed of light, then it obeys the SR.